# Nuxt keep-alive not working for router out-side. NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, router, keep-alive, nuxtjs

I have stuck, was unable to resolve all day.
my nuxt version: 2.10
my layout:

- header
- nuxt (keep-alive)
- footer

I use keep-alive in nuxt. and have 2 issue:

- 1. Using keep-alive-props max but it not happen anything.
- List item

[Img for issue 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmzl8.jpg)

- 2. When i add nuxt-link or router.push from home(/ - index) to footer/menu/question => and then click back browsers. - The page home still keep-alive all ( its OK ).
     But when i add nuxt-link or $router.push from `home` to deck/dm/detail or deck/dm/:id => and the i click back - The page home was re-render again (its wrong).

[Img - My router.js in nuxt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSG57.jpg)

Anyone can help me in this case?
Thanks you so much!